# NSString format not working on device but working on simulator

Tags: nsstring, swift2, nsuserdefaults

just making a basic game and used the NSUserDefaults to save the high score. while calling the i needed to use a NSString with a Format of "Best Time : %i". I Ran the game on the simulator and it worked perfectly.

However when I went to run it on the device the label that i formatted using the NSString(format "Best Time : %i") did not work nothing appeared in the label?

Here is the code I used for calling the saved Best time:

```
   //The previous games best time 

    var highscoreDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if (highscoreDefaults.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil){

   theNewTime = highscoreDefaults.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!

   thehighscore.text = NSString(format: "Best Time : %i" , theNewTime) as String


    }
```

//---------------------

Comment: What if `highscoreDefaults.valueForKey("Highscore")` does equal `nil`? Also, you should use `objectForKey()`, not `valueForKey()` to test if there's an entry. And, if there is, you should use `integerForKey()` get to the integer value, not `valueForKey()` nor `objectForKey()` cast to an `NSInteger`.

Comment: Thanks i swapped them over but still have the same issue of it working on the simulator but not on the device. Very annoying.

Comment: Edit your question to show your current code, including what you do if there's no objects in the defaults for "Highscore".

Comment: oh wait hold on your right i was missing the else statement that determines when highscoreDefaults.valueForKey("Highscore") does equal nil. so when this equals nil i will want my current time to equal theNewTime i think. just going to try it now and see. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift's string interpolation as you don't need any advanced features from the C-format specifier:

```
thehighscore.text = "Best Time : \(theNewTime)"
```

Comment: tried this but for some reason I'm getting the same result.